# Шрифты ttf и номер кодовой точки

Tags: шрифты, ttf

Подскажите пожалуйста, могут ли различные файлы TTF со шрифтами - содержать в себе один и тот же номер кодовой точки Юникод - НО при этом внутри каждого из файлов TTF - это будет разный символ ?
Теоретически ведь такого быть не должно, так как в Юникоде не может же быть на одном номере два символа ?

Comment: Да легко! Я вот могу открыть TTF в редакторе и сами глифы букв поменять местами. Да и потом, если вас интересует экзотика и не следование гайдлайнам Юникода, то один шрифтовик видит символ так, а другой - эдак.

Comment: @Kromster, спасибо, но все равно не понял. Ну вот предположим у менять есть текст в кодировке UTF8 на китайском "你好" - есть файл TTF с китайскими "символами". По какому прицнипе тогда программа, которая выводит текст в окно преобразует мою строку "你好" в видимый текст используя данные из файла TTF, если один и тот же иероглиф в разных файлах будет иметь разные номера ?

Comment: В юникоде есть диапазоны символов, определяемых пользователем (Private Use Area), каждый автор фонта рисует там что захочет.  Особенно актуально для емоджи.

Comment: По принципу того, что все собрались и договорились, что символ с номером, например, 65 выглядит как "А" и называется "большая латинская А". И назвали потом этот стандарт - Юникод. А все остальные посмотрели и согласились, что ок, годится, будет следовать вашему стандарту.

Comment: В шрифте записано какой символ юникода какому глифу соответствует. Причём может быть в зависимости от всяких настроек. Простейший пример символ `0` которого в шрифте может быть несколько версий (с точной, с перечёркиванием, пустой) и программа выбирает какой-то в зависимости от разных параметров. Обычно программы этим не занимаются а просят у какой-нибудь бибиотеки именно потому что это сложно и много нюансов.

Comment: @AlexeyTen не совсем так. Программа не "просит какой-нибудь символ похожий на овал". Программа всегда точно по алгоритму просит конкретный символ "ноль" или "латинскую O" или "кириллическую О" и может быть с конкретным модификатором (курсив, регистр, компоновка, итп). Но это всегда что-то точное.

Comment: @Kromster, если я правильно понимаю, то Вы дали два противоречащих друг другу ответа. Сначала Вы написали, что "Да" - различные файлы TTF могут содержать кодовые точки Юникод указывающие на разные символы, а потом - "Нет" не могут.

Comment: Optimus1, противоречия нет. Разбираем тот же пример. По стандарту, символ с кодовой точкой 65 называется "латинская буква А". По здравому смыслу и обычаю, художники рисуют ее как "А". Художник может нарисовать ее и как "/-\" - на это нет запретов. Зловредный маньяк может нарисовать ее и как "Б". То о чем говорит AlexeyTen, это когда вам надо видя глазами символ определить какая это кодовая точка - это нетривиальная задачка, т.к. в Юникоде и в реализующем его шрифте может быть десяток глифов выглядящих как "А" и/или называемых "такая-то А".

Comment: @Kromster, ну да, я не имел в виду «овал». Я имел в виду «дай мне символ ноль с параметрами zero=1, cv12=1 и т.п.» В той же FiraCode пять разных нулей :-) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIv0K.png

Comment: @Kromster, теперь лучше стал понимать :) Спасибо. А вообще такое часто случается ? Что тот кто составляет TTF файлы - делает так, что номер Юникода 65, которая указывает на общепризнанную "А" нарисует "Б" ? То есть не для того, чтобы поприкалываться или навредить, а вот по какой то другой не понятной причине ? Одно дело изобразить "А", как "/-\" , но совсем другое, как "Б"

Comment: Прямо так вредительски скорее нет. Но встречаются специальные шрифты, особенно старые (тот же Dignbat) из тех времён когда количество символов в  шрифте было ограничено (да и Unicode ещё не было). Ну и всякие декоративные тоже…

Comment: @Alexey Ten, а зачем пользоваться такими старыми шрифтами ? Теоретически же должны быть новые шрифты с четким соответствием номеру символа в юникоде ?

Comment: Вот например была история, когда хотели блокировать парсинг сайта. Снабдили его своим шрифтом с перемешанными глифами, и соответственно перемешали символы в показываемых строках. Глазами смотришь - все норм. Пытаешься скопировать текст куда-то - выходят белиберда.